# Is there any Dropbox Sync library available for java?

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I recently started doing a POC for integrating a java web-app with dropbox. I found that although there is a dropbox-core-sdk for java. But for some reasons dropbox has not provided sync libraries for java(The sync libraries are only available for android/ios).

1) Can we use the the android sync api  in a java web-app?

2) if not, then are there any libs available for sync api in java?

3) if not, how can we write it :) ?

Thanks,

Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can we use the the android sync api in a java web-app?

I don't know.  You'd have to try it out.  But I can think of a couple of reasons why it might not work:

- The Android download includes some Android (Linux) native libraries for x86, mips and arm.  There are no Windows DLLs (naturally).
- The Java code in the download is provided as Java bytecode files only.  I would expect those files to include dependencies on Android classes, which would be problematic for running them on a (real) Java platform.

> 2) are there any libs available for sync api in java?

I found this Eclipse library that apparently implements Dropbox sync: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/eclipse-sync/

I didn't investigate how Eclipse specific it is, but it is available in source code form.

> 3) how can we write it?

Start with the above.  Alternatively, you could track down the protocol spec (if there is one) and implement it from scratch.